# const and non const getter : C2248: cannot access private member declared in class

Tags: c++, constants

I have a class which implements a getter to an `std::vector`. Derived classes are allowed to change the content of the vector, while any other class may read it (or make a copy in my case), but not change it.

SSCCE with Visual Studio 2010 (but should compile with any other as well).

So in the base class I implemented the getter like this:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

    class X
    {
    public:
        inline std::vector<std::string> const &getChilds(void) const
        {
            return mChilds;
        }

        void mutateInternal(void)
        {
            mState != mState;
        }

    protected:
        inline std::vector<std::string> &getChilds(void)
        {
            return mChilds;
        }

    private:
        std::vector<std::string> mChilds;
        bool mState;
    };

// Now in the derived class

    class Y : public X
    {
    public:
        Y(void)
        {
            std::vector<std::string> &childs = getChilds();
            childs.push_back("Test");
        }

    };

// In the non derived class:

    class Z
    {
    public:
        void myfunction(void)
        {
            Y y;

            std::vector<std::string> s = y.getChilds();
            if(s.size() == 0)
                y.mutateInternal();

        }

    };


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

But I get the error

```
1>junk.cpp(49): error C2248: "X::getChilds": cannot access private member declared in class.
1>          junk.cpp(18): Siehe Deklaration von 'X::getChilds'
1>          junk.cpp(10): Siehe Deklaration von 'X'
```

and I don't really see what is wrong with that and why the compiler doesn't take the public version which is const and instead insists on the non-const.

Even if I change the variable to `const &s` (which wouldn't help in this case) I still get the same error.

### Update:

Edited the SSCCE for calling const and non const functions.

Comment: Use `std::vector<std::string> s = static_cast<const Y&>(y).getChilds();` instead

Comment: I'd never recommend using syntactic overloading, let alone overloading just in constness. I know this doesn't answer your question - that's why I write it as a comment.

Comment: A simple solution is to give the functions different names, but since you provide unrestricted access to subclasses anyway, the getter itself is questionable and the simplest solution is to make the member variable protected.

Comment: @molbdnilo, I found in my experience that getters are more usefull. They get optimized away usually, but when I need to change something (like logging access etc.) I don't have to modify my code anywhwere.

Comment: @molbdnilo, Direct access also doesn't allow me to change the implementation at a later date, because then I have a direct coupling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case it should be

```
const Y y;
```

in `Z::my_function` for call `const` version of function.
[Live](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/qmnEGoe4a8hUaZtQ)
Or just cast to `const Y`, like

```
std::vector<std::string> s = const_cast<const Y&>(y).getChilds();
```

Your case don't work, since access check will be applied only after overload resolution, in call `y.getChilds()` non-const overload will be picked, since it has the best match.

Comment: But wouldn't that mean that I can't call any non-const functions? After all, in some cases the class may need to update it's internal state (which is not shown in the SSCCE).

Comment: I updated my example. Anyway, I thought the compiler can deduce that on it's own. If I have to add this ugly cast, then I can just as well use an artifically different functionname, which makes the code cleaner to read.

Comment: @Devolus it can't, just because non-const version is best match, but it's in protected.

Comment: I think I understand now the problem (even though I don't like it :) ). Ok. Thanks!